# How to use toggle() in php in table while fetching the data from database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, toggle

**I want to use toggle() in table when i am fetching data from database, but its not working.**

The issue is loop which i am using in "id name" because if i remove the loop and give a unique id name, then it works properly, but i am fetching the data and data is more than hundreds and so it is not possible to give unique id name so i have given the id name in loop.

Code is :

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db('new game')or die('database not found');
?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title>Gaming Zone</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#$aa").click(function(){
$("#$bb").toggle(700);
});
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div align="right"><a href="admin/index.php">Add</a></div>
<table width="735" border="1" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td width="568">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <?php
$abc=mysql_query("select * from games order by game ASC");
$aa=0;
$bb=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($abc))
{
$aa=$aa+1;
$bb=$bb+1;
?>
    <td>
    <?php echo $row['game']; ?>&nbsp;<sub><a href="#" id="$aa">Requirements</a></sub><br>
        <div id="$bb" style="background-color:#FF3; display:none"><?php echo $row['min']; ?><span style="padding-left:50px"><?php echo $row['rec']; ?></span><span style="padding-left:100px"><?php echo $row['max']; ?></span></div>
</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Need for Help for **how to give unique id name when data is huge in amount ?** Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use a class instead of an ID, and use DOM navigation functions like `.parent()` and `.next()` to find the DIV that's after the one that was clicked.

Comment: thanks for helping but i am a new user and i don't know the use of .parent() and .next(). Can u please rectify the code and send it. Thanks once again.